# Highchart extend x-axis and then update y-axis data

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, trading

I am trying to build chart like expertoption.com and iqoption.com using highchart. I have no experience in the chart. Can anyone tell how to build a chart like expert option live chart?

please check the code below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
```

The issue is that I want the time axis to extend more than the current time.

I am trying to edit [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) realtime chart.

Below is the reference, I want to build this type of chart: [expert option chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgqYQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

To show more than the current time you can set `xAxis.overscroll` in Highstock like that:

```
  xAxis: {
    overscroll: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t43qfxh7/1/